# openlayers html/css, one div on an other one

Tags: html, css, openlayers

Here is what I want to have:

http://jsfiddle.net/nzcktv9e/

blue `div` on white one.
I copy and paste the same css/html to use them with openlayers and I get a map with: blue `div` on white `div` but at **top right**, and a white stripe of **15px height** on top (same height as `div id="coordexterne"` and this stripe is under the blue `div`).

I can't fix these two things. I think it is caused by openlayers css but I can't find what parameter.
Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like the parent may not really have applied `position:relative;`

Comment: Use chrome dev tools to check if the parent div really has position:relative; if not, make sure it has - give it for example an id and style that id to have position:relative;
But it would be best if you could upload your code so we could see whats going on.

Comment: it can be seen here : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119260/openlayers-display-control-mouseposition-on-div-olmap/119261?noredirect=1#comment169584_119261